# HTTP Post by android always return result 0

Tags: android, web-services, http, http-post

i supposed to send http post to web service in the form

POST[messageTitle, messageContent, messageFrom]

it's like array with the name post

i searched around and some people said i should do :

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("POST[]", messageTitle.getText().toString()));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("POST[]", messageContent.getId()));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("POST[]", messageFrom.getText().toString()));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

```
        // Execute HTTP Post Request

        try { 
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);                
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();       
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();         
            if (statusCode == 200) {              
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();      
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();       
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(               
                        new InputStreamReader(content));             
                String line;         
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {     
                    stringBuilder.append(line);      
                }           
            } else {               
                Log.e("JSON", "Failed to download file");  
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {      
            e.printStackTrace();       
        } catch (IOException e) {      
            e.printStackTrace();   
        } 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
    Log.d("Cat", stringBuilder.toString());
}
```

but it returned {"result":0}
and supposed to return {"result":"row"}

Comment: post your web service code

Comment: i don't have the web service code